# Custom tooltip color and font size in dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Is there any api in dimple to customize the tooltip color and the font type/size? I'm mainly looking for a way to do this for line and bar charts.

If that's not possible then is there an alternate/recommended way to do this via d3?

I tried searching for a way to do this in the dimple docs but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize with the CSS class `.dimple-custom-tooltip-box`.  Unfortunately, `dimple.js` styles a lot of the properties (like fill color) in-line on the element after the class, so you'll need to use a `!important` to override them:

```
  .dimple-custom-tooltip-box {
     fill: red !important;
  }
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSLjQ2eSOopZyO0lxFSM?p=preview).

**EDITS**

The `dimple-custom-tooltip-box` is missing on the tooltip for line charts.  Not sure why, [the docs](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#user-content-customClassList) indicate it should be there.  Regardless, switch the css to:

```
rect.dimple-tooltip {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

and it works for both chart types.

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKwcgVlsvhF27zsPLskq?p=preview).

Comment: If you don't want in-line styles you can set `chart.noFormats = true`.  This will remove all automatic styling and allow you to set it all via css.

Comment: thanks using CSS worked. I still have one problem however. I have 2 charts on my page (a bar and a line). For some reason this doesn't seem to work with the line chart. Does it use a different CSS class or am I still missing something?

Comment: @SHA1, looks like that class is missing in a line chart.  [According to the docs](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#user-content-customClassList), it should be there.  Regardless, see updated answer for a way to make it work.

Comment: @Mark excellent. thanks a lot that worked great. Also the corresponding css for the font is text.dimple-tooltip{} in case anyone else needs it

Comment: I want to change the font color inside the tooltip box, but havent been able to find anything on it since a day. Please help

Comment: @vinita `text.dimple-tooltip {
      fill: red !important;
    }`